# adding a where clause to a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a search form to my outputted list of results on a page.

The variable I'm using in the form is "term"

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
    <input style="margin-top:-16px; margin-left:10px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to change the foreach loop to work with the form, (at the moment it looks like this)

```
  <?php foreach ($data['page'] as $item): ?>
```

But I would like it to function like:

```
  <?php foreach ($data['page'] as $item) WHERE $item contains 'term': ?>
```

(I know the above is incorrect, but that's what I'm trying to acheive.)

Comment: could you elaborate further , what operation exactly do you want done on the $item variable ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to do so we can help you. If you're not interested enough in your question to provide what people ask you for, then why should we be interested in your question?

Comment: I was looking to do exactly what's in the answer below. only trouble is that the search only works if the exact entry is put in. Is there a way I can change the code below so that it works if the entry contains the value. e.g it will only find a result of "Wembley" by typing in "Wembley" - can I change it so that I can only type in "Wemb" for example, or a similar string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php 
    foreach ($data['page'] as $item) {
        if (in_array($_POST['term'], $item)) {
            // do your work.
        }
    }
?>
```

[`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) check if an element is in an array.

[`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is a PHP superglobal that contains all the POST data submitted to the current page using HTML forms which has `<form method="post">`. PHP superglobal means they are available in every PHP script without declaring them at the first place.

Comment: what is $data['page']?

Comment: thanks this was what I'm looking for. The only thing is the search at the moment has to be exactly the same as the entry. e.g it will only find a result of "Wembley" by typing in "Wembley" - can I change it so that I can only type in "Wemb" for example, or a similar string?

Comment: so basically, if the entry contains the string typed in into the search form... thanks for your help.

Comment: Ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm reading your question right, but I take it to be something like:

```
<?php
foreach ($data['page'] as $item) {
    if ($item == 'term') {
        // do something
    }
}
?>
```

or possibly

```
<?php
foreach ($data['page'] as $item) {
    if ($item == $_POST['term']) {
        // do something
    }
}
?>
```